# Adding a date format to FROM_UNIXTIME breaks query

Tags: mysql

Trying to run this query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(offers_consumers_history.date,
                     `'%d-%m-%Y')` AS date,
                     COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM (`offers_history`)
JOIN `offers_consumers_history` ON `offers_consumers_history`.`offer_history_id`=`offers_history`.`id`
WHERE `offers_history`.`merchant_id` = 1
  AND `offers_history`.`offer_type_id` = 1
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(offers_consumers_history.date))
ORDER BY `offers_consumers_history`.`date`
```

If I run it without a date format on my first FROM_UNIXTIME (the %d-%m-%Y part), everything runs fine, but I'm obviously not getting the right date format displayed, the returned error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`offers_history`) JOIN `offers_consumers_history` ON `offers_consumers_his' at line 2
```

Without a date format I'm getting results such as:

```
{"date":"2010-08-18 18:40:00","count":"2"}
```

What I want is:

```
{"date":"18-08-2010","count":"2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` is a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you can't use it as alias, use different name

```
'%d-%m-%Y') AS dt,
COUNT(*) AS cnt
```

OR with backticks

```
(offers_consumers_history.date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS `date`,
COUNT(*) AS `COUNT`
```

Comment: You lead me to the right answer, the problem was in `'%d-%m-%Y')`, I'm using codeigniter and forgot to set my select second parameter to false:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: Count is not a reserved word. Where do you get this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` from the table name and change the alias name of count:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(offers_consumers_history.date,
                     '%d-%m-%Y') AS `date`,
                     COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM `offers_history`
JOIN `offers_consumers_history` ON `offers_consumers_history`.`offer_history_id`=`offers_history`.`id`
WHERE `offers_history`.`merchant_id` = 1
  AND `offers_history`.`offer_type_id` = 1
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(offers_consumers_history.date))
ORDER BY `offers_consumers_history`.`date`
```